# Yii2: UrlRoute из модуля

Tags: yii2, url-manager

Знаю, тема довольно заезженная, но что-то у меня не получается

1. Создал модуль со своим нэймспейсом:

frontend\config\main-local.php

```
'bootstrap' => ['debug', 'gii', 'user'],
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => [
            'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
            'allowedIPs' => ['*']
        ],
        'debug' => [
            'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
            'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
        ],
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'garmayev\user\Module',
        ],
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        '@garmayev/user' => '@app/modules/user'
    ],
```

2. Пытаюсь сформировать правила роутинга в модуле:

@app\modules\user\Module.php

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module implements BootstrapInterface
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'garmayev\user\controllers';

    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        $app->getUrlManager()->addRules([
            [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlRule',
                'pattern' => $this->id.'/list',
                'route' => $this->id.'/default/index'
            ], [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlRule',
                'pattern' => $this->id . '/<controller:[\w\-]+>/',
                'route' => $this->id . '/<controller>/index'
            ], [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlRule',
                'pattern' => $this->id . '/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>',
                'route' => $this->id . '/<controller>/<action>'
            ],


        ], false);
    }

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // custom initialization code goes here
        \Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config/main.php'));
    }
}
```

3. UrlManager для остального сайта:

frontend\config\main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',
        '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Ошибки вроде бы очевидны:

При попытке открыть страницу user/list движок Yii2 (advanced) ищет контроллер user и экшн list (исходя из основных настроек в файле `frontend\config\main.php`) и соответственно вываливает ошибку 404

Вопрос: Как задать правила роутинга для модуля?

Answer (score 0):

Кажется урлы надо в инит добавить. Я бы вынес все правила в отдельный конфиг-файл, чтобы не захламлять класс модуля. А так как в этому конфиге рулсы только для модуля, то id модуля можно и строкой прописать.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    Yii::$app->urlManager->addRules(require __DIR__ . '/config/urlRules.php');
}
```